# How to solve chosen/jquery/frontend violation

Tags: joomla-3.x, jquery

I am developing a component for a Joomla frontend site and when I include `JHtml::_('formbehavior.chosen', 'select');` in the template form, I get this message in JavaScript Chrome Console (Mac OS X):

> [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchstart' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952

The message doesn't happen in Firefox, but I am supporting an older code for a client and beyond that message I get a really slow page load using chosen, even in Firefox.

Does anyone have an idea of how to solve this, or any alternative to chosen nowadays?

Comment: Welcome to JSE.  Please take the [tour] while you wait for support.

Comment: Even though jQuery Chosen is a deprecated/not maintained plugin it is not giving console error on its demo page, so I was not able to duplicate the issue you are writing about. You can check it here: https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: Hi @Zollie this error is in Joomla supplied version of chosen, but if you use Chrome (v. 85) for Mac OS X (v 10.15.6) the demo page also show message about violation

Comment: I figured out how to see the message in the development console on windows: On the console, there is a message filter, on windows the verbose message type is not active by default. Activating this level the messages appear in windows as well.

Comment: I use Chrome (v.85) and I see now that Joomla indeed is supplying an older `Version 1.6.2` of JQuery/Chosen and the last version of that is `1.8.7`. The test page of Chosen uses an older jQuery library too, however I still cannot get the console error. I mean I've seen the error but it came from the old jQuery library in the first place not from the Chosen script. I think alternatively you can try Select2 library, I have not checked that deeper yet but it does not look bad either. https://select2.org/

Comment: I would like to avoid using code outside what is offered in the official Joomla distribution, it becomes one more thing to manage, but if there is no other solution, maybe I will follow that idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the contribution of @mrentropy from the page https://stackoverflow.com/a/48098097/1390452, I wrote this code to resolve the messages:

```
jQuery.event.special.mousewheel = {
  setup: function( _, ns, handle ){
    if ( ns.includes("noPreventDefault") ) {
      this.addEventListener("mousewheel", handle, { passive: false });
    } else {
      this.addEventListener("mousewheel", handle, { passive: true });
    }
  }
};
jQuery.event.special.touchstart = {
  setup: function( _, ns, handle ){
    if ( ns.includes("noPreventDefault") ) {
      this.addEventListener("touchstart", handle, { passive: false });
    } else {
      this.addEventListener("touchstart", handle, { passive: true });
    }
  }
};
jQuery.event.special.touchmove = {
  setup: function( _, ns, handle ){
    if ( ns.includes("noPreventDefault") ) {
      this.addEventListener("touchmove", handle, { passive: false });
    } else {
      this.addEventListener("touchmove", handle, { passive: true });
    }
  }
};
```

The three events need to be rewritten as above, when using the code `JHtml::_('formbehavior.chosen', 'select');`.

Comment: Please be sure to accept your answer so that the system understands that this page is resolved.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with your code, but just in case it's helpful I'm using this method for including the library and I do not see your error.

```
use \Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper;
use \Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use \Joomla\CMS\Uri\Uri;
use \Joomla\CMS\Router\Route;
use \Joomla\CMS\Layout\LayoutHelper;
use \Joomla\CMS\Language\Text;

HTMLHelper::_('bootstrap.tooltip');
HTMLHelper::_('behavior.multiselect');
HTMLHelper::_('formbehavior.chosen', 'select');
```

**Update:**

I was curious and read a bit more about this, and it seems the error actually comes from jQuery. This Stack Overflow thread discusses in more detail and offers a few JavaScript solutions.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48098097/1390452

Comment: I do that, same response.

Comment: Hi @mrentropy,

 I checked out your suggestion, and get an solution based in some response there:
    
    jQuery.event.special.mousewheel = {
      setup: function( _, ns, handle ){
        if ( ns.includes("noPreventDefault") ) {
          this.addEventListener("mousewheel", handle, { passive: false });
        } else {
          this.addEventListener("mousewheel", handle, { passive: true });
        }
      }
    };

I needed to do this to _mousewheel_, _touchstart_ and _touchmove_ events.

Comment: That's terrific, Bruno! Way to go on resolving the mystery.